# Multiple shorthands for if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the syntax for multiple if shorthands in JavaScript?

```
$('#field-'+i+' .name').css({
    top: '30%',
    width: '100%',
    'letter-spacing': i==1 ? '-2.5px' : '-1px',
});
```

I want letter-spacing to have multiple shorthands like:

```
'letter-spacing': i==1 ? '-2.5px' i==3 ? '-1.5px' : '-1px'
```

Comment: Thats not shorthand thats cryptic.

Comment: Why don't you just set these things in CSS?

Comment: @ahren: CSS is limited to one value only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i === 1 ? '-2.5px' : i === 3 ? '-1.5px' : '-1px'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the shortest one. =))

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is nothing wrong or bad to inline multiple ternery operators if you want to have it in a single line of code, but you could use a more readable style there.

However, my suggestion here is to use a lookup-object or an *Array*, especially if you have a lot of different states.

```
var values = ['1px', '-2.5px', '5px', '-1.5px'];

$('#field-'+i+' .name').css({
    top: '30%',
    width: '100%',
    'letter-spacing': values[ i ],
});
```

Comment: Extra coding is not necessary if there are only two possible values.

Comment: @Radio: "multiple" often times means more than "two" values, I think.

Comment: @Radio: ok you didn't get it. OP is talking about "multiple" values, so the code actually might be just an example. As stated in the answer, a lookup or array comes in very handy with more values. Nevermind.

Comment: You just posted that "multiple" !== "two", then deleted it. I'm getting it right. =)

Comment: #Radio Actually in many languages "multiple" means more than two. In Ancient Greek for example, there were singular, dual and plural (grammatical) numbers: [Dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(grammatical_number))

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a `:` to finish out your first conditional:

I added some parens to help a little:

`'letter-spacing': (i == 1) ? '2.5px' : ((i == 3) ? '-1.5px' : '-1px')`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're talking about nested ternary expressions - I tend to indent like the following:

```
'letter-spacing': i==1 
    ? '-2.5px' 
    : i==3 
        ? '-1.5px' 
        : '-1px'
```

Comment: I don't know if I can as a comment, I'll add _another_ answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

If you have lots of choices, consider a hash:

```
var hash = {
    1: '-2.5px',
    3: '-1.5px'
};
```

and then:

```
'letter-spacing': hash[i] || '-1px'
```

If your `i` is an integer, you can use an array, instead of a hash-object. However, the object is more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

@ChrisFrancis: A tabular ternary variation:

```
`'letter-spacing': i == 1 ? '-2.5px' 
                 : i == 3 ? '-1.5px'
                 :          '-1px'
```

Maybe a little confusing in this case with the first ":" meaning something else, but season to taste

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks! Yeah, that's actually a nice representation. Maybe I'll start doing that from now on! :)